# Python Itertools Add List for Every Combination

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I need to create every combination for `list1`, but add `list2` to every combination of list1.

For example, this creates a combination for every value for `list1`:

```
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = ["d", "e"]
list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

But I would like the result to be:

```
[('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'c'', d', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

I have tried these common approaches, but am getting undesired results:

```
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = ["d", "e"]
print(list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2)).extend(list2))
None

print(list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2)) + list2)
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), 'd', 'e']

print(list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2) + list2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'itertools.combinations' and 'list'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's no such shortcut, best write a list comprehension.

Comment: I updated the code for with two different purposes!

Comment: How would you do it if your intermediate result `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]` *didn't* come from using `itertools.combinations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first generate a tuple of size 2 combinations for each list separately, then compute the cartesian product of those to combination lists:

```py
import itertools
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = ["d", "e"]

iter1 = itertools.combinations(list1, 2)
iter2 = itertools.combinations(list2, 2)

# If you want to add a subset of size 2 from list 2: 
product = itertools.product(iter1, iter2)
answer = list(map(lambda x: (*x[0], *x[1]), product))
# [('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

However, if you want to add all elements of `list2` you can use:

```py
import itertools
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = ["d", "e", "f"]

iter1 = itertools.combinations(list1, 2)

# If you want to add all elements of list2
product = itertools.product(iter1, [list2])
answer = list(map(lambda x: (*x[0], *x[1]), product))
# [('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')]
```